# Propositional logic, valid entailment

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus

I have an old exam-question but don't know how to solve
this type of problems. So If someone could give me a hint  it would be much appreciated.

Is the following entailment valid?

$$
(p \rightarrow q) \rightarrow r, \neg r\land \neg s, (q \rightarrow p) \lor t, t \rightarrow (r \lor p) \vdash t
$$

If I assume that the right handside is false$(\neg t)$ and show that the left handside holds, then the entailment is not valid. But how?

EDIT

For 
$$
\neg r \land \neg s  
$$
to be true then both  r and s must be false. 
And if r is false then $$(p \rightarrow q)$$ must be false.
 And since $$(q \rightarrow p)$$ must be true, then p is true and q is false.

When t is negated, all premises is satisfiable and therefor the entailment is not valid. Am I right?

Comment: Have you made any progress?

Comment: Oh. Thanks for asking. Not really. I'm I a making it more complicated when adding a negation to 't'(right hand side)?

Comment: Yes, indeed; since the conclusion may be false with all premises satisfied, therefore $t$ is not entailed by those premises.

Comment: I have now tried this when assuming t is false and when t is true. Both times all premises is true if p is true and q is false. Is it then correct to say that the entailment is not valid but satisfiable?

Comment: Yes, and therefore....

Comment: Not sure what you mean here but since they ask if the entailment is valid, the answer should be no, it is not.

Comment: ...t is not entailed by the premises.

Answer (score 1):

If all of the premises and the negation of the conclusion can **be satisfied**, then the conclusion is not a logical entailment of the premises.

$$\{(p \rightarrow q) \rightarrow r, \neg r\land \neg s, (q \rightarrow p) \lor t, t \rightarrow (r \lor p), \neg t\}$$

Clearly, the *negation of the conclusion* may be satisfied when $t$ is false.  That also satisfies the fourth premise, but the third premise would then only be satisfied when $q$ implies $p$.

$$\{(p \rightarrow q) \rightarrow r, \neg r\land \neg s, (q \rightarrow p) \lor \bot, \bot \rightarrow (r \lor p), \neg \bot\}$$

Carry on..

Comment: When you say it also satisfies the fourth premise, do you mean that (r v p) could be either true or false here?

Comment: Yes, @LarsLogik . $t\to(r\vee p)$ is satisfied when $\lnot t$ is; so that does not fix $r$ or $p$. For that, look to the second premise, $\lnot r\land\lnot s$.